# How to import MailItem.EntryID into MS Access table using "Import Outlook Folder" feature

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

Is there a way to edit settings of the built-in "Import Outlook Folder" feature in access and include more of the fields/properties that exist for every email?

Thank you in advance.

I've been using "Import Outlook Folder" feature in MS Access (Office 365) and it does import some of the Outlook.Mailitem properties (such as: Subject, Body, Sender, ReceivedDate etc.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Z3Q.png)

But many of the properties are missing like MailItem.EntryID which is the unique key/id of every mail. And i want to get that EntryID in order to be able track every email in Outlook and display it if necessary.

Now i know how to loop through outlook folder content with VBA GetNamespace("MAPI") method but i think it is inefficiently slow process.

Comment: Direct answer - No.